# In a function, how to access different columns of a dataframe passed as argument?

Tags: r, function

I want to write a function with a vector and a dataframe as arguments

```
myfunction <- function (vector, dataframe) {

 result <- dataframe$??[match(vector,dataframe$??)]

}
```

What should I replace the ?? with to access respectively the second and the first column?

Comment: Maybe `result <- dataframe[, vector]`??

Comment: `myfun <- function(DF,cols=TRUE) DF[,cols,drop=FALSE]` just in case you pass a vector of length zero or one...you could set cols=FALSE if you want nothing in the former case.

Comment: fortune(312)! -- `dataframe[[1]][match(vector,dataframe[[2]]]`